# How to set ruby variables in ruby script to shell environment variables

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog, aws-sdk, secret-key

I want to write a ruby script using fog (a wrapper for aws-sdk). Of course I could hard code my aws secret key and ID but would like to be able to have it set dynamically to my shell env variable since I manage multiple accounts.

```
require 'fog'
require 'json'
require 'logger'

aws_key_id = $aws_key_id
aws_secret_key = $aws_secret_key
queue_url = $sqs_queue_url
```

Would this work?

Comment: sorry I didn't get.. do you you want to read from the env variables or write to it from a ruby script?

Comment: Yeah I would want to have my bash env variables be changing on the cli... and then when I run the script the ruby variables would change accordingly. So read from the env variables.

Answer (score 6):

In ruby you use `ENV` to access those values.

```
require 'fog'
require 'json'
require 'logger'

aws_key_id = ENV['aws_key_id']
aws_secret_key = ENV['aws_secret_key']
queue_url = ENV['sqs_queue_url']
```

If you want to provide default values, you can use `ENV.fetch('key', [default])`: `ENV.fetch('sqs_queue_url', 'http://localhost')`